# Add New Columns that Repeat Min and Max Dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a column for the Line # and a column for the date that Line # was invoiced for.  I want to create two new columns: one column that repeats the Min date for the Line # and another column that repeats the Max date for the Line #.

Here is the original table:
[image]

Here is what I want the result to be:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want each row in the table in the output, but with the first and last Month values for that Line # value added. This should do the job on most SQL platforms.

```
SELECT a.Month, a.LineNumber, b.FirstMonth, b.LastMonth
FROM {yourtable} a
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT LineNumber, FirstMonth = MIN(Month), LastMonth = MAX(Month)
        FROM {yourtable}
        GROUP BY LineNumber) b
    ON a.LineNumber = b.LineNumber
ORDER BY a.LineNumber, a.Month;
```

Comment: Hi Sqlhead - thanks so much for the reply.  That worked like a charm!  Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQL Server windowing function like this:

```
--demo setup
Declare @t table ([month] date, linenumber int)
insert into @t([month],linenumber) values
('12/30/2018',123), ('1/29/2019',123),
('7/30/2018',789), ('8/29/2019',789)

SELECT [month]
    ,linenumber
    ,min([month]) OVER (PARTITION BY linenumber) AS mininvoicedate
    ,max([month]) OVER (PARTITION BY linenumber) AS maxinvoicedate
FROM @t
```

---

```
| month      | linenumber | mininvoicedate | maxinvoicedate |
|------------|------------|----------------|----------------|
| 2018-12-30 | 123        | 2018-12-30     | 2019-01-29     |
| 2019-01-29 | 123        | 2018-12-30     | 2019-01-29     |
| 2018-07-30 | 789        | 2018-07-30     | 2019-08-29     |
| 2019-08-29 | 789        | 2018-07-30     | 2019-08-29     |
```

---

For more information about SQL Server windowing functions, check out the documentation in this post [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your response. I'm very new to SQL, so apologies in advance. I'm not sure what a SQL Server windowing function is.

I'm actually using a BI tool called Sisense, which is based off of SQL queries.  I'm not sure if the SQL Server windowing function is available in Sisense.  I tried writing your code in Sisense and the "Over" and "Partition" lines were not recognized.  

Any other feedback on a solution that may work for me?  Or maybe some more insight into getting your solution to work with Sisense?  Thanks!